# Do I need a comma in this sentence?

Tags: commas, clauses

The sentence in question is as follows: "are these alcohol shakes or something else?"

I want to correct it to "are these alcohol shakes, or is it something else?", but I can't update the post title, and I want to believe that I didn't make an incredibly stupid grammatical mistake

Answer (score 5):

I'm not entirely sure I understand the exact question, but:

1. "are these alcohol shakes or something else?"

If you capitalize the first letter of the sentence, it's perfectly fine. It does not need a comma.

> "**A**re these alcohol shakes or something else?"

2. "are these alcohol shakes, or is it something else?"

You can write it with or without a comma. Personally, I wouldn't use a comma. However, if this were dialogue in a play, for example, the comma might indicate that the speaker should pause briefly.

You must make the subject of the second thought agree with the first thought, however.

`Are these (plural) ==> are they (plural)`

You should also capitalize the first letter of the sentence.

> "**A**re these alcohol shakes, or **are they** something else?"

Comment: thanks for your response. this was just a silly advice forum post, and I, like most people, know that the first word of a sentence is supposed to be capitalized, but I do appreciate your taking the time to respond.

Comment: I don't know why, but the version with the comma sounds like the "correct" version to me, and I can't shake the feeling that the alternative is wrong! I'm anal about commas, and that really sucks, most of the time

Comment: @blankname the final two commas in your last comment being proof of that I guess

Comment: Since the original post contained a comma, I used a comma in the example. Like most written text, it's all about context. Think about the sentence spoken with and without a comma. It potentially changes the intent and the meaning. But I think both are correct.